# How to define a range greater than X

Tags: ruby

I'm afraid I already know the answer but is there a way to define in Ruby 3.2 a range greater than 1?

Since

```rb
(..1.0).include?(1.0) => true
(...1.0).include?(1.0) => false
```

I was expecting `(1.0...)` to create what I need but,

```rb
(1.0..).include?(1.0) => true
(1.0...).include?(1.0) => true
```

Comment: Ranges can only exclude the end element, not the starting one. If you just want to check whether the object is larger than 1, there's `obj > 1`.

Comment: If you're dealing with floats, you can use `(1.0.next_float..)` to create a range that starts one float after `1.0`.

Comment: You might find [this discussion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12133) of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, although there are workarounds.
From the docs at https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Range.html#class-Range-label-Beginless+Ranges

> A beginless range has a definite end value, but a nil begin value. Such a range includes all values up to the end value.
> The literal for an endless range may be written with either two dots or three. The range has the same elements, either way. But note that the two are not equal...

The key point is that only the end is documented as being possible to exclude.

One workaround is

```
!(..1.0).include?(other_number)
```

The `!` means "not", so the meaning here would be "not in negative infinity to 1"

```
!(..1.0).include?(1.01)
# => true
!(..1.0).include?(1.00)
# => false
!(..1.0).include?(0.99)
# => false
```

Technically, this isn't a range that is all numbers greater than one, but it has the same effect.

You could subclass range to get custom behavior.

```
class ExclusionaryRange < Range
  def include?(other)
    !(self.end..self.begin).include?(other)
  end
end

my_range = ExclusionaryRange.new(1.0, nil)
my_range.include?(1.0)
# => false
my_range.include?(1.1)
# => true
my_range.include?(0.9)
# => false
```

Comment: `!(..1.0).include?(other_number)` works for the example given in the question, but the question is, "I'm afraid I already know the answer but is there a way to define in Ruby 3.2 a range greater than 1?". You have not answered that question, and negation cannot always be used. For example, if we were to use the range `1..`, on the understanding that `1` was not to be included, in this way: `(1..).find { |n| n == 4 }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with floats, you can utilize the fact that there is a finite amount of floating point numbers (Ruby uses 64-bit binary floats aka "[double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)" internally). You can get a floating point's successor via [`next_float`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Float.html#method-i-next_float):

```
1.0.next_float #=> 1.0000000000000002
```

The output of `1.0000000000000002` is a rounded representation for convenience. The number's exact value is 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625. There's no other (64-bit binary) floating point number above 1.0 that's closer to 1.0.

If you start your range at this float, it will effectively skip `1.0`:

```
(1.0.next_float..).include?(1.0)    #=> false
(1.0.next_float..).include?(1.0001) #=> true
```

Note that the typical floating point oddities still apply:

```
(0.3.next_float..).include?(0.3)       #=> false
(0.3.next_float..).include?(0.1 + 0.2) #=> true
```